# Knockout JS: adding forms in foreach bindings

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I would like to add a 'delete comment' button as a form that triggers an ajax request next to each comment that is generated using knockout's foreach binding. `comments` is an observable array, each comment is an object with `username`, `text`, `timestamp` and `commentID` members. Loading the following without the `<form>` element works fine:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: comments">
    <li>
        <span data-bind="text: username"></span>
        <ul>
            <li data-bind="text: text"></li>
            <li data-bind="text: timestamp"></li>
            <form data-bind="if: sameUser" method="post" action="deleteComment.php">
                <input data-bind="attr: {id: commentID}, click: deleteComment" type="submit" value="Delete comment">
            </form>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

However, including a `<form>` element breaks the foreach loop, only one comment is loaded.

I want to use the `if: sameUser` data-bind so that the delete button is only visible to the user that posted the comment, and the 
 `attr: {id: commentID}` data-bind to send the right comment ID to delete to the server when the button is clicked, but right now my main concern is loading the form/button in the first place.

What is the correct way to go about this?

Comment: does sameUser exist on the objects inside the comments array? If not you might need to use `if: $parent.sameUser()`

Comment: also recommend checking your console to see if bindings are broken, it usually spits out an error with the offending binding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Not sure if you are writing delete function on comment level or its list level but if are binding the function use **$parent** to get out of foreach context.

Following is the working example

```js
function viewModel() {
  var self = this;
  
  self.comments = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.isDataLoaded = ko.observable(false);
  
  self.loadData = function(){
    setTimeout(function(){ 
      self.comments.push({username:"A", sameUser:true, commentID:1, text:"This is comment from A"});
      self.comments.push({username:"B", sameUser:true, commentID:2, text:"This is comment from B"});
      self.comments.push({username:"C", sameUser:false, commentID:3, text:"This is comment from C"});
      self.comments.push({username:"D", sameUser:true, commentID:4, text:"This is comment from D"});
      self.isDataLoaded(true);
    }, 2000);
  }
  self.deleteComment = function(data){
    self.comments.remove(data);
  }
}

var vm = new viewModel();
vm.loadData();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul data-bind="foreach: comments">
    <li>
        <span data-bind="text: username"></span>
        <ul>
            <li data-bind="text: text"></li>
            <!--<li data-bind="text: timestamp"></li> -->
            <form data-bind="if: sameUser" method="post">
                <input data-bind="attr: {id: commentID}, click: $parent.deleteComment" type="submit"        value="Delete comment">
            </form>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thank you, though I still don't understand how your `deleteComment` function works...how does it know which comment to delete? what is `data` in `function(data)`?

Comment: @Rookierookie, $parent.deleteComment click event sends the current object by default to function(data) and object.remove() method can accept object to be deleted from list OR u can send commentId and find list item to delete manually.
Please feel free to comment if you still need clarification.